# unexpected changes in authselect

Tags: linux, pam

Hi guys my authselect error shows that
/etc/authselect/system-auth has unexpected content!
unexpected changes to the configuration were detected.
Refusing to activate profile unless those changes are removed or overwrite is requested

So how do i figure out those unexpected content??

Comment: You don't mention what command you use or what your configuration looks like, and the error messages probably looks a bit different than what you say, right? Something like what's shown in [the Troubleshooting section of the `authselect` manual](https://www.mankier.com/8/authselect#Troubleshooting)?  Consider updating your question with more information about what context you see the errors in, and also format your text so that your command(s) and the errors are clearly distinguishable from the rest of the text.